# Ubuntu 12.10 cant resolve characters inside firefox searchbar for Google, Youtube?

Tags: firefox, fonts

when I type inside the search bar in Youtube or Google, the letters typed are not displayed although the characters are being recognised by the engine and produce autocomplete results that are visible. I did download a fresh copy of ff via sudo apt-get firefox reinstall as suggested but this unfortunately did not work. The search pane for Google in the top most header to the left address bar does in fact show the characters as bold.
with firefox in safe mode, the problem is corrected

Comment: "intellisense"?  The correct word is "autocomplete".

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Apparently re-installing doesn't help

---

run firefox from the terminal in safe mode and see if the issue remains.

```
firefox -safe-mode
```

If it works in safe mode, some plugin might be responsible for the voodoo

---

If you have addons disable them one by one to determine which one is causing it. If you have no addons installed, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: yeah,I gave it a shot in Google and Youtube search panes and , with a restart,  it did not work. I checked Google Search in Chromium and it had no such issue. Would really like to figure the root cause of this... maybe an ubuntu font famil issue?

Comment: it worked with ff in safe mode

Comment: Ok its solved. I had the appearance setting as 'high contrast inverse' once I switched this back it worked fine even after a restart. putting it in safe mode made the search bar highlight blue in inverse and the letters display white.